# Large scale data processing, foreign API's, and loading bars

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, api, curl

I am using two separate and distinct API's from two websites (Site 1 => my App => Site 2). Pulling (get) in data from one site's API and sending (post) data to the other site. There is a layer of synchronizing AKA "fill in the cracks" (always keeping the sending site's data mirrored with the source), as well as a layer of non-duplication (making sure dataset from SITE 1 does not have duplicate entries on SITE 2).

When the user induces the "synchronization" through a simple form POST button. Potentially thousands of entries from SITE 1 need to be brought into SITE 2. The simple low-level way of doing this would be to take an array of data from SITE 1 loop it and in that loop I'd have a function that takes the data and sends it off to SITE 2. When working on a large scale this kind of a loop would most-definitely fail or hang for minutes terminating when the page is exited.

Here's an example of the "low-level / low-tech" way of doing it. In which each part of this example is very time consuming. All operations occurring on one-page / one-script, which the user can stop. The page would be white, blank, and not very user friendly.

```
// Get all of the data from site one
$siteOneDataNuggets = get_siteOne_data();

//Loop through all of site one's data
foreach($siteOneDataNuggets as $siteOneDataNugget){

  //Post it to site two
  post_siteTwo_data($siteOneDataNugget);

}
```

When having a process like this that can take a while I would love to show some sort of loading screen / bar. How would something like this be implemented as well.

I am looking for a coding-philosophy or standard way of dealing with my above situation. Ideas and theory are what I'm looking for, not necessarily code examples.

**My own preconceived alternative.**

Another way of doing this potentially would be to have a page that would act as a localized "API" that I could request, each with its own instance of `$siteOneDataNugget` spreading the logic across 1000's of pages instead of 1 single page. Most likely done with ajax feeding the loading bar / presentation layer.

**Progress Report**

I've wen't deep into the alternative. Started out with PHP CURL and when I figured out that was going to take hours to load (triggered 4 minute timeout) I stumbled across [EpiCurl](https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl) explained in this [blog post by Jaisen Mathai](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/php-curl-asynchronous.html) which uses asynchronous curl calls. Which has its own [limitation](https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl/issues/6) I have yet to conquer.

Comment: why not load it in the background, users don't want to have to wait.

Comment: I guess that raises the question, How do you load something in the background, which I'm googling right now.

Comment: well at work i call the file that imports the data like so: exec("nohup php file.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &"); then send notification to user when its done

Comment: I may have to adjust my server memory which I don't know is possible or not with dreamhost. I feel like this can equally be done with ajax, just ping the page with the massive loop on it. Not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was way ahead of my time on this one. What I was doing was really dumb I was making thousands of AJAX requests to my server which did some action. What I should have been doing was using WebSockets / socket.io that way I could have had some sort of two way communication between Client and Server and been able to handle bulk operations and progress bars.

At the time of this question both were in their infancy.

- [WebSocket Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)
- [Socket.io's first commit](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/commit/1514af064f7b9a319df2e87a7da6f3cc0f07ce16)